# SQL select values with or

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to make a query which does the following

> select a,b or c,d from table where source=2 or target=2;

I want to select a,b if the source=2 or c,d if the target=2.

Is this possible with SQL statements?

Comment: What is source and target ?

Comment: In what case you need to get a and b or c and d? What is the condition?

Comment: Er... `SELECT ... FROM <database>`? That makes no sense. You `SELECT` from a *table*. Do you want to select from two different tables? If so, that's often possible using a `UNION` or `UNION ALL`. Please provide (a lot) more detail. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info for guidance on asking better questions. What does this have to do with Java or Android, anyway?

Comment: @CraigRinger You are right. It should be a table and not a database. I will correct this.

Comment: @JunedAhsan I think it doesn't matter waht source and target is or? It's just a SQL statement. a,b,c,d and source and target are columns in my table. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a,b
from database
where source = 2

union

select c,d
from database
where target = 2
```

For Working Example Check [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/e0c66/3)

Comment: Probably should be UNION ALL, not UNION

Comment: Union is okay, because I want only one result not all.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you have a table called 'database' (an awful name for a table) which looks something like this:

```
  a   |  b   |  c   |  d   | source | target 
------+------+------+------+--------+--------
   11 |   22 |   33 |   44 |      1 |      2
  111 |  222 |  333 |  444 |      2 |      2
 1111 | 2222 | 3333 | 4444 |      2 |      1
```

You can then query it like this:

```
select
   case when source=2 then a else null end as a,
   case when source=2 then b else null end as b,
   case when target=2 then c else null end as c,
   case when target=2 then d else null end as d
from database;
```

and get this result:

```
    a |    b |    c |    d 
------+------+------+------
      |      |   33 |   44
  111 |  222 |  333 |  444
 1111 | 2222 |      |
```

As required, only a and b are returned where source=2, and c and c are returned where target=2.

Answer (score 3):

You can:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html

A statement such as this should do what you want, although I have no postgresql around to test with:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN source = 2 THEN a, b
        WHEN target = 2 THEN c, d
        ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: It is news to me that Postgres supports `a, b` for a `then` clause.  Can you provide documentation that it violates the standard in this way?  I can't seem to replicate it.

Comment: That's not working. It says there is an error in line two next to the coma.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
select a,b,c,d from (select a,b from database where source=2 UNION select c,d from database where target=2)
```